# How to join two separate files on one corresponding column?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sorting, join

I'm trying to join two files on one column, but join and sort command gives me following output:

```
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

File 1:

```
TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server, OI-QASDWDASDWQWD,
TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server, OI-WASDWDASDWWWW,
TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS, REGAA638G0K,
TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS, REGAA55410K,
```

File 2:

```
SERVER1; Deployed; REGAA638G0K;
SERVER2; Deployed; OI-WASDWDASDWWWW;
SERVER3; Delete; OI-QASDWDASDWQWD;
SERVER4; Delete; REGAA55410K;
```

Expected File 3:

```
SERVER1; Deployed; TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS;
SERVER2; Deployed; TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server;
SERVER3; Delete; TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server;
SERVER4; Delete; TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS;
```

My command:

```
join -1 2 -2 3 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 <(sort -t"," -k2 spmGroupsModifiedSCLine.out) <(sort -t";" -k3 spmCompStatJoined.out)
```

The second column in first file and third column in second file are the same so I'm trying to join on it and sort it first. Do you see other way to do the join? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }$3 in a{ print $1,$2,a[$3] }' FS=',' file1 FS=';' OFS='; ' file2
```

The output:

```
SERVER1;  Deployed; TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS
SERVER2;  Deployed; TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server
SERVER3;  Delete; TEST->Infrastructure->Global Windows Server
SERVER4;  Delete; TEST->Infrastructure->zSeries_MVS
```

Comment: Is it possible to leave those columns which didn't join in a file too? As for now as I see it shows only the data which is joined.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as the `awk` solution but perhaps more intuitive:

```
cat file2 | while read line; do
  key=$(cut -d';' -f3 <<< $line)
  echo "$(cut -d';' -f1-2 <<< $line); $(grep $key file1 | cut -d',' -f1);" >> file3
done
```

or

```
cat file2 | while read line; do key=$(cut -d';' -f3 <<< $line); echo "$(cut -d';' -f1-2 <<< $line); $(grep $key file1 | cut -d',' -f1);"; done > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use join.

```
join -t ';' -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,1.1 <(sort -t , -k 2 File\ 1 | tr ',' ';') <(sort -t ';' -k 3 File\ 2) | sort > File\ 3
```

Comment: Is it possible to leave those columns which didn't join in a file too? As for now as I see it shows only the data which is joined.

Comment: Yes and No, with join you lose the format of the file. You can try            join -v 1 -v 2 -t ';' -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,1.1 <(sort -t , -k 2 File\ 1 | tr ',' ';') <(sort -t ';' -k 3 File\ 2).                                                                              It' s better to use awk solution from RomanPerekhrest .                                                                               awk 'NR==FNR{b[$2]=$0;a[$2]=$1;next}$3 in a{a[$3]=1}!($3 in a){print}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]!=1) print b[i]}' FS=',' File\ 1 FS=';' OFS='; ' File\ 2